# Can I Publish Dynamics 365 Portal Pages from TFS/VSTS

Tags: portal, dynamics-365, adxstudio-portals

My team and I are exploring code versioning for Dynamics 365 Portal Pages. We intend to use an editor/IDE to develop pages and scripts for the portal and check them in into TFS/VSTS, instead of using the inline editor on the Dynamics 365. Is there a way that these codes can be published directly onto the Portal without manual intervention?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you will need to write some code.

The web pages in CRM are just normal records, so you can use the SDK to import and export them like any other record.

You could make an application to do that, and then use that within the VSTS Build and Release pipeline.